# How to test Google Plus API (Google Plus test account)?

Tags: google-plus

I am pretty sure I missed something, but I couldn't find (ie. google) a possibility to create test accounts for Google Plus.
However, it is surely not allowed to create fake user account for tests, so, how do I test my G+ apps with more than one (my) account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you point out, your Google+ account should be created using your [common name](http://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1228271), but you are not limited to one profile. For manual testing you can create a second profile.

If you are doing automated testing, though, this is probably not an effective approach. Your tests will consume your quota so whenever possible mock the client library to test your code.

Comment: Sure, mocking is the way to go, however, it would have been nice to do some final real world testing. How do I create a second profile?

Comment: I suspect you're over-thinking it ;)  Simply log out, navigate to http://plus.google.com and sign up using the regular sign up flow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089877/how-to-test-google-plus-account-existance/25090598#25090598