# How to test Google Plus account existance

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-account

I am building a website where a user could specify his social accounts links, I am trying to find a way to test if a google plus account actually exists (social account validation).

I've seen that it is actually possible to test using the *GET people/userId* but what about curtom urls ? For example if a user has a google.com/+JohnDoe , how would you figure it out? I didn't find anything in the google docs.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same API. `GET people/userId` and `GET people/+JohnDoe` both work.

Comment: oh thank's :D i've tried GET people/JohnDoe, I missed the "+"

Comment: @user3521418: please select an answer if the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

i think google never publish users info or google's huge database, because spammers are searching very hard to that API (for advertising,....)
but you can implement this algorithm:

1. save ID as string (for example id="mohsensolhnia" or 21 digit number)
2. redirect to "http://plus.googleapis.com/wm/4/+"+id+"/posts"
3. if link was wrong you will redirect to "error 404 page"(google page not found) (title is "Error 404 (Not Found)!!1" ;D ;D )

you can do above 3 step  with C#/java/phyton/... "[selenium webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)" dll very easy.

Comment: Thank's, that's actually a good workarround :)
but i think since they have the api, they wouldn't block us from using it, it would be stupid i guess